# MongoDB find objects with key exists and value equal to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, mongodb

I am trying to build a custom ACL for my application.

My data structure is as follows:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("345sdf345dsf"),
  allowedResources: {
    "GET /auth": true,
    "POST /verify": false
  }
}
```

How can I write a query to find documents with `allowedResources["POST /verify"]` key as `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  "allowedResources.POST /verify": true
})
```

Try it here : [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bCuecDqObxS)